# PySpark LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS Import error

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, logistic-regression

I am trying to use the pysoark LogisticRegression library.Below is part of my code:

```
    from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
    from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
    from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel,   LogisticRegressionWithSGD
    from pyspark import SparkContext
```

I am getting the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "LogisticRegression.py", line 3, in <module> 
    from pyspark.mllib.classification import    LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel, LogisticRegressionWithSGD
    ImportError: cannot import name LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS
```

Is there a circular import dependency here?I am using Python 2.7.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say your version of pyspark is outdated.

Try :

```
pip freeze | grep pyspark
```

`LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` class was introduced in pyspark 1.2.0.

To upgrade your version of pyspark you can use `pip` as well :

```
pip install pyspark --upgrade
```

**Edit :**

@ShuaiYuan comment's seems right and you can't use pip for pyspark.

Comment: Thanks..(Works fine now)

Comment: How can you `pip install pyspark` ? It is not available as a Pypi package. [Reason](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1267?focusedCommentId=14192279&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14192279).